# Searching a CSV file Java

Tags: java, file, search, csv

Im trying to a specific String of number in a csv file and I keep getting an a FileNotFound exception even though the files exists. I cant seem to fix the problem 
Sample Csv file

12141895, LM051
12148963, Lm402
12418954, Lm876

User Input : 12141895

Desired Result : True

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.List;


public class tester
{
public static void main (String [] args ) throws IOException
{

    boolean cool = checkValidID();
    System.out.println(cool);
}

public static boolean checkValidID() throws IOException
{
    boolean results = false;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Packard Bell\\Desktop\\ProjectOOD\\IDandCourse.csv"));
    String s;
    int indexfound=-1;
    String words[] = new String[500];
    String word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your student ID");


   while (scan.hasNextLine()) 
   {
    s = scan.nextLine();
    if(s.indexOf(word)>-1)
        indexfound++; 

    }
if (indexfound>-1)
{ 
    results = true;
}
 else 
 {
    results = true;
 }
 return results;
}
}
```

Comment: please please double check if the file really exists..

Comment: check with **new File("C:\\Users\\Packard Bell\\Desktop\\ProjectOOD\\IDandCourse.csv").exists()**

Comment: Check your filename. Some people hide extension names and mistakenly type "filename.csv.csv" without realizing that their files already had extensions.

Answer (score 0):

use:

> import java.io.File;
>
> import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

Also, in your function declaration try using

```
public static boolean checkValidID() throws FileNotFoundException
```

and likewise with the main function.
If the file is present and named correctly, this should handle it.